# remover una cantidad específica de dígitos en variable php

Tags: php, php7

Me interesa remover 5 digítos de atrás hacia adelante en la variable *var_nums* no puedo especificar cuáles porque se obtienen automáticamente ¿Cómo lo puedo lograr?

```
$var_nums = "125469856554";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para remover los primeros 5 digitos

```
$var_nums2 =  substr($var_nums, 5)
```

Para remover los últimos 5 dígitos

```
$var_nums2 = substr($var_nums, 0, -5)
```

Aquí la documentación por cualquier duda:
https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.substr.php

Espero sirva, quedo a las órdenes.

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta esta referida a quitar los **últimos 5 dígitos** y colocarlos en la parte **delantera**.

Existen muchas maneras de hacerlo:

```
// Una variable numérica de cualquier cantidad de dígitos

$numero = "111111111222222222";
```

La función tomara la parte trasera y delantera para guardarlas en las variables $numeroAtras y $numeroAdelante respectivamente.

```
function mover_digitos($numero) {
    $numeroAtras = substr($numero, 0, -5);
    $numeroAdelante = substr($numero, -5);
    $numero = $numeroAdelante . $numeroAtras; // unifica las dos partes
    return $numero; // devuelve variable numero modificada
}
```

Ahora imprimimos el valor que entrega la función **mover_digitos($numero)**

```
echo mover_digitos($numero);
```

El resultado:

```
 222221111111112222
```